# Issue running MVC project while editing a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

To put it simple, whenever i run (debug) my MVC project while focusing a View (in the editor window) on Visual Studio 2012, the web page shown on the browser is the View itself rather than the actual landing page.

For example:
If my usual landing page is the following:

```
http://localhost:53338/
```

Then if i'm focusing the 'Add' View and I Run my project, it sends me here:

```
http://localhost:53338/Views/Products/Add.cshtml
```

Any idea how to 'fix' this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web debug configurations are set to run the "*Current Page*".

**Here are the steps on how to solve it:**

1. Go to the project's Properties (Right-Click on the project -> Click on *Properties*).
2. Go to the *Web* tab.
3. Select the *Start URL* radio button and leave the address text-box blank.
4. In the *Project URL* type: `http://localhost:[portNumber]/`

Good luck